# Is c_str() or reinterpret_cast better for working with binary files?

Tags: c++, file, binary, reinterpret-cast, c-str

I need to work with binary files in a program and I've seen reinterpret_cast used, as well as c_str().

Here is a code snippet using c_str():

```
fstream aFile;
string sample = "hello this is a line of code";
aFile.open("newFile.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
aFile.write(sample.c_str(), sample.size());
aFile.close();
```

Here is a code snippet using reinterpret_cast:

```
fstream aFile_2;
string sample_2 = "hello this is a line of code";
aFile_2.open("newFile_2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
aFile_2.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sample_2), sizeof(sample_2));
aFile_2.close();
```

And when I write to the binary file that used reinterpret_cast, I get gibberish... When I read the data back into my program, it makes sense. 
When I use c_str() however, the data makes sense in the file I wrote it to (no gibberish).

And, after using c_str() to write to the file, I can easily retrieve the data using getline or >>:

```
string result = "";
aFile.open("newFile.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
//aFile >> result;
getline(aFile, result);
cout << "result = " << result << endl;
aFile.close();
```

So, my questions are, which is better to use for binary files: reinterpret_cast or c_str()? And why?

Personally it seems that c_str() is better...

Thank you all :)

Comment: `aFile_2.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sample_2), sizeof(sample_2));` Won't work. `std::string` contains details that will be very poorly handled by `write` and ultimately fatal when read back.

Comment: You can't reasonably cast a `std::string` to `char*`, thus your question doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: `aFile.write(sample.c_str(), sample.size());` leaves you with no way to recover the length of the string when reading the file back out if there is more in the file than just the string. Either include the terminating null or prefix the string with the length of the string (preferably in a type with known endian and length)

Comment: Neither are good for binary data, but then neither of your examples really has anything to do with binary data. I'd use a vector so nobody gets confused and tries to treat my data with embedded zeroes as a string.

Comment: *Personally it seems that c_str() is better...* `c_str()` is possible. The other isn't. `c_str()` wins! Flawless victory!

Comment: On ubuntu 64, with g++ 7.3, for 'std::string s': the sizeof(s) is 32 bytes regardless of s.size().  The object s does not contain char data, instead, s has counters and pointers to where it keeps the char's (in dynamic memory).   reinterpret_cast<> fails with non-pod data.  Even if you saw the second code style, you did not see it work.

Comment: "When I read the data back into my program, it makes sense" -- purely bad luck that it even seems to work. This might be happening because you try it during the same program execution, but you would never be able to read it again from a different program or after restarting the same program with different options. Or it might be happening because of Small String Optimization, in which case when the string gets long enough, that accident will also stop happening.

Answer (score 0):

While the behaviour of `aFile_2.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sample_2), sizeof(sample_2));` is well defined, the state of the `std::string` object is meaningless outside of the process. To clarify, this does not write the content of the buffer managed by the `std::string` object. If your intention is to write gibberish to the file, then this is better.

`aFile.write(sample.c_str(), sample.size());` does write the content of the string buffer (i.e. "hello this is a line of code" in this case), which I presume is what you intend. If so, this is better. I would personally use `sample.data()` instead, although it doesn't matter much. Furthermore, I would use a vector instead of `std::string` to represent binary data, since the latter is intended for null terminated text.

As for reading, `getline` is not useful for reading a binary file. It works in this case, since the content is textual.

Comment: What would be the proper way to do it? Could you please provide some code, and if you can, some links?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense.

A file is a stream of bytes. Before you can write data to a file, you have to decide how to express that data as a stream of bytes. You need to decide precisely what information needs to be in the file and how it will be represented as bytes. This may also entail documenting how you determine how many bytes need to be read and how it is determined what information is stored where in the file.

Then you can write code that writes data in that agreed format. You can write code that reads data that's stored in that format.

But you can't analyze code in the absence of an understanding of precisely what information is to be recorded and how it's to be recorded. The code snippet that writes the data required in the format decide on is best. It is literally impossible to tell if data is written correctly if you don't know how it's going to be read or what information is supposed to be written in what format.